# How to use HTML in Listbox for desktop application

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I want to use `HTML` in `ListBox` item, so I want to do that

```
 listBox1.Items.Add("It's <b> Bold</b> Text");
```

But It didn't succeeded. 
Note: I am using C#.net of VS 2013 
Please help

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: If it is WinForms, it does not support that.

Comment: Is there workaround to do some words in the item bold or colored without HTML?

Comment: There is but it requires lots of code I think. As you need to do your own drawing of the UI (the OnPaint event). There is only one WinForms standard control I know of that supports different text types in one line and that is RichTextBox. Any other control is normally just one font with one style and size. If you write your own ListBox or inherit the .Net ListBox and do your own painting you can achieve what you are looking for. Or maybe try a hacky way by using a WebBrowser control, insert HTML there and work with that.

Comment: You would have to set to `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawxx` and code in the `DrawItem` event. Not really that hard, once you are a little acquainted with GDI+.

Comment: BTW, yes it is a duplicate, but all the answers in the link are rather weak, to put it mildly.. Look for OwnerDraw..